# Fetch event .focusout from input field in table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, jquery-events

First, I have a Google visualisation dataTable.

After that I create a `for` loop to get table cell values and put then in input fields:

```
for (var y = 0, maxrows = data.getNumberOfRows(); y < maxrows; y++) {
    for (var x = 1, maxcols = data.getNumberOfColumns(); x < maxcols; x++) {

      data.setValue(y, x, '<input id="costRedovi" vr="'+ data.getValue(y,0) + '" kol="'+ data.getColumnLabel(x) +'" class="form-control" value="'+data.getValue(y,x)+'">');
    }
}
```

Now every value is into table cell into input field. Now I can change those values when table is ready, but how to get those values now because  my script produce this HTML code now. Also I need to get value on event `.focusout` on an input field:

```html
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even google-visualization-table-tr-sel">
   <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input id="costRedovi" vr="2013-04-01" kol="John Deer n7" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
   <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input id="costRedovi" vr="2013-04-01" kol="Laza Lazic" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
</tr>
```

I tried to do this:

```js
new google.visualization.events.addListener(table, 'ready', function () {

    $("#costRedovi").focusout(function() {
        console.log($('#costRedovi').attr('value'));                        
    });

});
```

The problem is that every input has the same ID now.

Comment: ID's are unique, every input can't have the same ID.

Comment: you can create the table dynamically and you can set your id like costRedovi + fieldNumber. Also please finish your last sentence.

Comment: i will try with class...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were to use a class instead of an ID, that is:

```
<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-even google-visualization-table-tr-sel">
  <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input vr="2013-04-01" kol="John Deer n7" class="form-control costRedovi" value="0"></td>
  <td class="google-visualization-table-td"><input vr="2013-04-01" kol="Laza Lazic" class="form-control costRedovi" value="0"></td>
</tr>
```

You could then retrieve the unfocused-input like so:

```
$(".costRedovi").focusout(function() {
  var origval = $(this).attr('value');
  var editedval = $(this).val();

  console.log("before: " + origval + ", after:" + editedval);
});
```

Comment: very nice, thanks, the solution was class instead id's